# PHP - Check if previous value of foreach equals the current value

Tags: php, html

I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [from] => Person 1 [to] => Person 2 [content] => Hello )
    [1] => Array ( [from] => Person 1 [to] => Person 2 [content] => How are you? )
    [2] => Array ( [from] => Person 2 [to] => Person 1 [content] => Oh, hey there. I'm fine )
    [3] => Array ( [from] => Person 2 [to] => Person 1 [content] => What about you? )
)
```

And I want to loop through it, so that if current `[from]` equals the previous `[from]`, then a `<p>` element containing the `[content]` as inner HTML is created. If it is not equal, then create a `<div>` is created and the `[content]` is displayed.

So, the output should be:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>How are you?</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Oh, hey there. I'm fine</p>
    <p>What about you?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to make sure that current `[from]` to not equal to immediately previous `[from]` or any previously traversed `[from]` ? In the later case the solution would be different.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul If it is not equal to immediately previous `[from]`, then a `<div>` element is created.

Comment: @alej27 Was my answer not satisfactory, or did you want someone else to do *all* the work for you?

Comment: @FrankerZ It was; I already have the code that works for me. I was just waiting in case someone wrote something more compact or who knows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through it using a for loop instead:

```
$count = count($array);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $item = $array[$i];
    $lastFrom = null;
    if ($i > 0) {
        $lastFrom = $array[$i-1]['from'];
    }

    if ($item['from'] !== $lastFrom) {
        // Item is different, do different things here
    }
}
```

Or, store `$lastFrom` in your loop:

```
$lastFrom = null;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['from'] !== $lastFrom) {
        // Item is different, do different things here
    }

    $lastFrom = $item['from'];
}
```